# how do I concatenate a variable and string to show an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a variable stored in localStorage from a button click. How do I display an image that has the same name as the variable + .png using jQuery? I can't seem to get the right syntax...I'm very new to this and I appreciate any help!!!

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('key') + '.png'`

Comment: var + '.png' did not work for you?

Comment: Please post a bit of code to show what you are trying and exactly what about it isn't working.

Comment: I tried this:<div>img src="'images/' + adj1 + '.png'"</div>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some brackets.  Try

```
"<div><img src=\"images" + adj1 + ".png\" ></div>"
```